# android: pixel Depth of device

Tags: pixel, depth, android

I'd like to know if it's possible to get the pixel depth (number of colours) of a device.
with DisplayMetrics it is possible to know the resolution...

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

But where can I find the pixel depth ?